# Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I know this topic is discussed a lot of times here, but I am still stuck on an exception:
Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key.

(I am using spring data and hibernate)

My ID class:

```
    @Embeddable
public class ProxyDienstRelationPK implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column
    private String parentDienstId;
    @Column
    private String subDienstId;


    public ProxyDienstRelationPK(){}

    public ProxyDienstRelationPK(ProxyDienst parentDienst, ProxyDienst subDienst){
        this.parentDienstId = parentDienst.getId();
        this.subDienstId = subDienst.getId();
    }

   //Getter and Setter , HashCode and Equals

}
```

My Entity:

```
    @Entity
public class ProxyDienstRelation {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProxyDienstRelationPK pdId;

    private ProxyDienst subDienst;

    private ProxyDienst parentDienst;


    private boolean modul;

    //Getter and Setter   
}
```

I get for this construction the following exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_ad3h9gu4labg6ix34bei3poxt:proxy_dienst_relation [parent_dienst_id,sub_dienst_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (proxy_dienst [id])
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:110)
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:93)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1816)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1739)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1424)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
>       ... 23 more

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@MapsId("subDienstId")
@ManyToOne
private ProxyDienst subDienst;

@MapsId("parentDienstId")
@ManyToOne
private ProxyDienst parentDienst;
```

In your case `parentDienstId` is part of PK but also plays role as a FK. This is called "Derived Identities". There is a good chapter about it in Pro JPA 2 book.

Comment: It seems to work. I have no while starting my application. Thanks a lot.